# Properties of Entire Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

a). 
Suppose an entire function f is bounded by M along $\vert z \vert = R$. Show that the coefficients $C_k$ in its power series expansion about $0$ satisfy $ \vert C_k \vert \leq \frac{M}{R^k} $.

I know that an entire function is infinitely differentiable and can be represented as a power series $C_k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{k}(0)}{k!}z^k$. However, I am not too sure what is meant by $M$.

Source: I am using the *Complex Analysis, Third Edition* textbook by Bak and Newman.

Comment: [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula).

Comment: No source, no sign of effort by OP, no indication of what OP knows, where OP gets stuck ... voting to close.

Comment: [How to ask a homework question.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)

Comment: It would probably be best to ask just one of the two questions here.  You can ask the second one separately.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I just edited the question.